# Restricting resources of user applications

Tags: kernel, performance, ram, cpu

Sometimes, either because of a memory leak or the computationally-intensive nature of a program, applications can start to slow down and ultimately freeze the whole system by claiming too much RAM or CPU time (or at least I think that's what's happening - please enlighten me if it's more complicated). I was wondering if it was possible to ringfence a certain amount of RAM or 'CPU time' for use purely by important system applications (basically anything not explicitly started by me - including the desktop environment) so that a greedy application can't freeze the whole system.

If it is possible, I'd also be curious as to why Ubuntu doesn't do it by default.

Comment: Yes - its possible using cgroups. Refer to [cgroups doc](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/cgroups/cgroups.txt?v=3.15). There are lots of examples on the net could search.