# How to limit resource usage for a given process?

Tags: configuration, cpu, process, memory-usage, io

I have a process for an application which needs to run, but ends up using far too much IO usage for what it does. And really crashes my computer, making it impossible to do anything else whilst it is running.

So I was wondering if there is a way to limit IO usage, RAM and CPU for a given process? And its sub-processes of course.

This is on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system.

Comment: @GreatUncleBulgaria Not really, unless you want to part with reputation points.  The simple answer to what you ask is to just combine what others suggested -  `ionice`, `renice` - and perhaps `ulimit -s` commands, and that's it.

Comment: @GreatUncleBulgaria Not familiar with `cgroups-io` so have no idea :)

Comment: Potentially related question: https://askubuntu.com/q/538992/295286 The answers there mention cgroups, but not much else, so . . . maybe ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy: Looks like someone cleaned the comments up!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use a combination of all `cgexec`, `cpulimit` and `ionice`:

1. Limit RAM and SWAP:

   ```bsh
   sudo cgcreate -g memory:/szMyGroup
   echo $(( 512 * 1024 * 1024 )) | sudo tee /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/szMyGroup/memory.limit_in_bytes
   echo $(( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ))  | sudo tee /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/szMyGroup/memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes
   ```

   The above commands create a control group named `szMyGroup` (E.g. in your case `group-great-uncle`), set a cap to the processes run under `szMyGroup` up to 512 MB of physical memory and up to 1024 MB of swap and then:

   ```bsh
   sudo cgexec -g memory:szMyGroup szMyProgram
   ```

   which will run your program under the `szMyGroup` control group, thus ensuring they adhere to the limits
2. limit the disk IO:

   ```bsh
   sudo ionice --class 3 --pid $(pgrep -f szMyProgram)
   ```

   The above command uses `pgrep` with [reusing parts of the current command-line](https://askubuntu.com/a/1048302/295286) to limit its disk access to only use the disk when *no other program is using it*
3. Limit the CPU:

   ```bsh
   sudo cpulimit --limit=25 --pid=!#:4
   ```

   The program's CPU is now limited to 25% of maximum

If the program does not use a lot of CPU to begin with, lower the value of cpulimit to half or less of what it currently uses.